# Responsive Email - Media Query Center

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have this table that has a logo in it.

```
<td class="header" style="padding: 10px 20px 0 10px;">
  <table  align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px 0 0 10px;">
       <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <table width="335" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
  <![endif]-->
  <table class="col325" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 325px;padding-top:10px;">  
    <tr>
      <td height="55" bgcolor="#deecf7" style="text-align:center;color:#000;font-weight:bold;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
```

And as you can see i have align="left" but i would like this to be centered from a media query on the mobile version how can i override that align="left"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got this to work, so i figured i would post how I got it to work in case someone else is having a similar issue.

This is the magic of the media query to clear the max-width that i have inline in the style below

```
body[yahoo] .logo{max-width:none !important;text-align: center;}
```

This is the entire td for the header.

```
<td class="header" style="padding: 10px 20px 0 10px;">
  <table  align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="logo" style="width:100%;max-width:220px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px 0 0 10px;">
       <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <table width="335" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
  <![endif]-->
  <table class="col325" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 325px;padding-top:10px;">  
    <tr>
      <td height="55" bgcolor="#deecf7" style="text-align:center;color:#000;font-weight:bold;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
```

Comment: `max-width` doesn't work in Outlook '07, '10 and '13. You wont get a consistent result with it without using it in combination with conditionals (to fake it in the above mentioned Outlooks).

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to have this Table "Centered" then you can do like below:

```
<div align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px 0 0 10px;">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

As it will show your table in the "Center", it will be a kinda Responsive for all the Devices.

Comment: This wont work because if i center it from a div or table it centers the desktop version, it also pushes the table i have next to it to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a parent element and toggle the width of your image table.

Align left:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#DDDDDD">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">

      <table bgcolor="#CCCCCC" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
           <img src="images/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="Logo" style="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now use media queries to alter the width of the inner table. Here I just put it inline to demonstrate:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#DDDDDD">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">

      <table bgcolor="#CCCCCC" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100px !important;">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
           <img src="images/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="Logo" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is some great out of the box thinking but in this case i dont think it will work for me, i probably should have started with my HTML update above. I have 2 tables next to each other in a single td for the header. I am doing this because when we get into the smaller screen sizes those tables become width 100% and and are stacked on top of each other. I might need to do this padding or something in a media query hmmm....

Comment: Why do you have the Outlook conditional - do you not want it so show up on web clients like Gmail and Yahoo when viewed on a desktop? Is it a workaround because they don't support media queries?

Comment: I am using the conditional outlook for the occasional time where Gmail and Yahoo will render it perfectly at 160px but outlook will need it to be 150 i have no idea why its needed for outlook but sometimes it helps so i have just gotten in the habit of adding it. I want it look 100% the same in all the desktop clients (Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail, iCloud and of course Outlook 2003-2013) But then responsive on iOS and the Androids that it works with. I am working on a hack similar to yours :) you got me thinking outside the box

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it is because in some Outlooks it sets the width at 100% plus the parents padding (pop to the next line), while other clients will treat it as 100% of the space inside the padding. If you remove the padding in your parent container you won't need the conditionals. Instead of padding the parent, pad the child's `<td>` and nest inside that if you need a border or bgcolor to offset.